# why it showing (current) in pagination by using reactjs

Tags: javascript, react-native, datatables, react-hooks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTaZ1.png)

return (
<>

```
 <MDBDataTable
        data={data}
        entries={10}
        striped
        bordered
        responsive
        hover
        noBottomColumns 
        noRecordsFoundLabel
        // info={false}
        
    />

 
</>
```

);

I used this code, pagination is working fine but the current name character showing in paginantion, how i remove this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as per docs [MDDataTable Pagination](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/pagination/#advanced-table-options) without giving any entries?

```
<MDBDataTable
      striped
      bordered
      small
      data={data}
    />
```

I am assuming it's mostly with some additional props you are passing.

Comment: yes i tried, still showing "current" string

Comment: @ShikhaRani Sorry for the delay, I have tried with your instructions. It's working fine https://imgur.com/a/cH39RBa. Maybe a giithub repo would be helpful.